# Can I connect GitExtension to Azure GIT repo

Tags: git-extensions, azure-repos

I am used to working with GitExtension for connecting and working(pull/push) with GIT repository hosted on-premise. My company is planning to create an Azure GIT Repo for hosting the code.

Will my local installation of GitExtension be able to pull/push the code from Azure GIT Repo? Are there any prerequisites I will need, to work with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pre-reqs, add another remote for the AzDO repo.

Edit:

Had to run these commands in Git Bash if Azure Url is behind proxy.

```
git config --global https.proxy <Your proxy Url>
git config --global http.proxy <Your proxy Url>
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```